# Regex - how to match a block comment

Tags: c#, regex

when it comes to regex I'm always lost. I have an editor created in C# to work with papyrus scripting, the problem I'm having is that users ask me for styling block comment ";/ /;" already working for single line that use ";"

Here is the code I have so far
var inputData = @"comment test and this line not suppose to show
;/
comment line 1
comment line 2
comment line 3
/;
Not suppose to show";

```
        PapyrusCommentRegex1 = new Regex(@"(;/\*.*?\/;)|(.*\/;)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        
        foreach (Match match in PapyrusCommentRegex1.Matches(inputData))
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(match.Value + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

The result I get is

comment test and this line not suppose to show
;/
comment line 1
comment line 2
comment line 3
/;

All the line before the ";/" shows.
My question is what am I doing wrong in my regex expression?
Thanks in advance to all

Edit:
To make it more clearer I need a regex pattern in C# for finding all block comment that start with ";/" and finish with "/;" and need to include the ";/ /;"

Comment: Unless Papyrus is one of the few languages in the world without strings, you have the problem `";/this is a string, not a comment/;"`

Comment: Yes you are right so how to fix this because I have no clue

Comment: Try removing the `\\` chars from your pattern. Unclear what you wanted to do, but they seems to be wrong. Resolving how to handle not-comments inside strings is different and more complex.

Comment: Not worried about inside the string new pattern (;/*.*?/;)|(.*/;) make no change at all. I want to create a style for block comment in the editor

Comment: According to http://forums.ultraedit.com/papyrus-creation-kit-comments-t18261.html, comments are one of the following formats: Following a semi-colon: `;this is an inline comment` or between `;/` and `/;` such as `;/this is a block comment/;`

Comment: I know that, and that's what I'm asking the pattern for ;/this is a block comment/;. This question isn't about papyrus scripting it's about C# coding regex to find in text the comment block

Comment: From your OP, it wasn't clear. It's not clear if you are trying to detect the comments or everything except the comments. You don't have to use Regex, you could read it character-by-character, keeping track of the current character and the previous char.

Comment: It as to be regex because of the library i'm using. I specified many time "to find in text the comment block"

Comment: When it find the block comment it apply a style to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3b%2f.*%3f%2f%3b%29%7c%28%3b.*%3f%28%3f%3d%24%7c%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%29%29&i=%3bsingle+line+comment%0d%0acomment+test+and+this+line+not+suppose+to+show%0d%0a%3b%2f%0d%0acomment+line+1%0d%0acomment+line+2%0d%0acomment+line+3%0d%0a%2f%3b%0d%0aNot+suppose+to+show%0d%0adsda%3b%2funclosed+multiline+comment+treated+as+single+line+comment%0d%0acontinues%0d%0a&o=s):

```
(;/.*?/;)|(;.*?(?=$|[\r\n]))
```

Note that I'm still using the `SingleLine` mode.

The part before the `|` matches multiline comments, the part after the `|` matches single line comments (comments that end when they encounter the end of the text `$` or a new line `\r` or \n`. Note that the regex won't capture the end-of-the-line at the end of the single-line comments, so

```
;xyz\n
```

the `\n` won't be captured. To capture it:

```
(;/.*?/;)|(;.*?(?:$|\r\n?|\n))
```

Comment: Works perfectly no need to change anything, the update of the application is already up and will see in the next few days if it's OK

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you need to do this with regex in a .NET library I guess you may want a regex that is using balancing groups to match the block comment

```
(?x)  # ignore spaces and comments
(
;/                 # open block comment
(?:
  (?<open> ;/ )*   # open++
  .+
  (?<-open> /; )*  # open--
)+
/;                 # close
(?(open)(?!))      # fail if unblanaced: open > 0
)
```

This should give you what you want. [Regex Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fx%29%20%20%23%20ignore%20spaces%20and%20comments%0D%0A%28%0D%0A%3B%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20open%20block%20comment%0D%0A%28%3F%3A%0D%0A%20%20%28%3F%3Copen%3E%20%3B%2F%20%29*%20%20%20%23%20open%2B%2B%0D%0A%20%20.%2B%0D%0A%20%20%28%3F%3C-open%3E%20%2F%3B%20%29*%20%20%23%20open--%0D%0A%29%2B%0D%0A%2F%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20close%0D%0A%28%3F%28open%29%28%3F!%29%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20fail%20if%20unblanaced%3A%20open%20%3E%200%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%7C%0D%0A%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Copenq%3E%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%5B%5E%22%5D*%3F%0D%0A%20%20%28%3F%3C-openq%3E%22%29*%0D%0A%29%2B%28%3F%28openq%29%28%3F!%29%29&i=dfajkdsjfk%0D%0Aaaa%20%3B%2Fzzzz%2F%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%22%3B%2Fthis%20is%20a%20string%2C%20not%20a%20comment%2F%3B%22%0D%0Aaaa%20%3B%2Fzthis%20is%20is%20%22cool%22zzz%2F%3B&o=x)

---

Some mentioned the problem of block comments in strings (and vice vesa?!). This makes things a lot harder, especially since we do not have the `(*SKIP)((*FAIL)` backtracking verbs and `\K` in .NET's regex engine available. I would try to match and *capture* what you need but only match what you do *not* need:

This matches your block comments and "..." strings. The trick is to only look at the `blockcomment` capture group:

```
(?x)  # ignore spaces and comments
(
;/                 # open block comment
(?:
  (?<open> ;/ )*   # open++
  .+
  (?<-open> /; )*  # open--
)+
/;                 # close
(?(open)(?!))      # fail if unblanaced: open > 0
)
|
(?:(?<openq>")
  [^"]*?
  (?<-openq>")*
)+(?(openq)(?!))
```

[Demo Code](https://ideone.com/7XNH1P)

I hope you can apply this in your code.

Comment: block comments in strings is not important at all for me at this time. Your first example works fine but very slow "5 secs" if you have only one block comment but if you add another block comment with a few line between them it will fail, it will return the 2 comments plus all the lines between them

Comment: @superl I see. Balancing Groups are not the fastest but it was working fine in my arbitrary samples. How long is a normal text, or can you provide a sample?
Here's a more optimized version if you are interested: `(?>;/(?:(?<open>;/)*.+(?<-open>/;)*)+/;)(?(open)(?!))`

Comment: xanatos answer works great, as for the length it's scripting and can go over 1000 lines, Thanks for the help